# Where did I go wrong in virtualenv installation on OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I followed the instructions carefully at http://jamie.curle.io/blog/installing-pip-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-os-x/

Restarted my terminal and typed `mkvirtualenv`, got a `command not found`

looked in `/usr/local/bin` and `ls` shows me:

```
brew                    powerpc-apple-darwin8-gfortran-4.2
charm                   tclsh8.5
django-admin.py             tclsh8.6
django-admin.pyc            virtualenv
gfortran-4.2                virtualenv-2.7
gfortran-uninstall          virtualenv-clone
i686-apple-darwin8-gfortran-4.2     virtualenvwrapper.sh
node                    virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
pip                 wish8.5
pip2                    wish8.6
```

So I know it's in the correct directory. I don't understand where I could have screwed up.

Comment: Did you add the sourcing of virtualenvwrapper.sh to your shell init scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked article recommends adding the line `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` to `bash` login profile file **`~/.bash_login`**.

However,

- `~/.bash_login` is **rarely used.**
- it is **NOT read if the much more common (on OS X) `~/.bash_profile` also exists.**

Thus,

- Check if you have a `~/.bash_profile` file
- and, if so, add the line `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` *there*.

My recommendation is to *never* use `~/.bash_login`. If you find other content, there, also add it to `~/.bash_profile`, and delete `~/.bash_login`.

Alternatively, if you're looking for *cross-platform compatibility*, put all definitions in `~/.bashrc` instead, and add only `[[ -e ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile`.